# Homebrew (OS X), gdal, and gdal2tiles.py/python

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles, homebrew

I had a previous installation of `gdal` (v. 1.11.5_3) that included in its binaries python files like `gdal2tiles.py`. I recently upgraded gdal with to 2.2.4 using Homebrew, but the result seems to have removed the python functions.

Is there an additional step that I should take?